# trying VirtueMart 2 on Joomla3

Tags: virtuemart

Trying setup VirtueMart on Joomla3 and It got me can't find .XML setup

I'm on an iMac.

1. I put the zip on a public folder called "VirtueMart2"
2. I login into Joomla3 and I go to Extension manager then I hit VirtueMart2 and select the .Zip.
3. When click on "Go" and Joomla got me this error message " I can't find setup.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the ([Virtuemart Project's downloads page](http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/files)), they have a listing of all versions available for download, as opposed to just downloading the latest stable version from [The Virtuemart website's downloads page](http://virtuemart.net/downloads). At the time of writing this post, 2.6.6 is the latest stable version, but you'll note that it says:

> 2.6.6 (stable, compatible Joomla 2.5)

Further down ont he list, you will see:

> 2.9 (Test versions, compatible Joomla 2.5 and 3.x)

Download the file fromt hat list that works best for you, and you should be fine :)

I was banging my head over this for some time, but this worked for me. Joomla 2.5 doesn't recognize the xml file in the 2.6.6 version as a valid installer, because the format is different for Joomla 3.0 extensions.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you always will get this error, because this package was build for Joomla 2.5.

Pls, try this link: http://dev.virtuemart.net/attachments/download/756/com_virtuemart.2.9.6_extract_first.zip